# Is there any tool that analyzes JavaScript code with own coding convention, and generates reports about it?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, static-analysis

I need to define a coding convention for JavaScript, that analyzes the code statically, and then generates reports.

All the tools I've seen are web-based, or do not have the option of defining personalized convention, or don't generate reports.

Does a tool like this exist?

Comment: Yes. [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/) and [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) are both extremely customizable. The latter, in particular, has hundreds of rules that can be enabled or disabled, and most have configuration options themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Teamscale](http://teamscale.com). It has a large number of rules defined for JavaScript and allows you to implement *Custom Checks* on top of that. You can access the analysis results in your IDE, your browser or via the well-documented REST-API (in case you want to generate your own reports).